# Open source blog hosting platform

Tags: open-source, wordpress, blog, newsletter

Is there any open source blog-hosting platform?

By that I don't mean something like Ghost or Wordpress, which I can deploy and use for a single blog, but something like the "as a service" version of those, where I can create user and then. in turn, allow them to create their own blogs.

I want to use this platform as the basis for another project, not quite in this way, but finding something like this open-source would be a great starting point and save me weeks of work.

Comment: "as a service" and "open source" are directly opposites.

Answer (score 1):

It's not open source, but [Mighty Networks](https://www.mightynetworks.com/) is a social network-as-a-service that allows you to create your own social network, on which your users can post or comment.

See [Mighty Communities](https://community.mightynetworks.com/feed) for example.

[image: Mighty Communities screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try Mastodon.

It's basically Twitter, but free as in freedom, open source, and distributed. Word counts and other rules are set by the instance owner. [Here](https://joinmastodon.org/servers)'s a list of servers/instances.

PS: "As a service" is a very bad moniker for this kind of thing. As a service software usually refer to something that only one website runs, instead of something you're free to download redist and run on your own. Richard Stallman even wrote [an essay](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/who-does-that-server-really-serve.html) against it.